# Bind WMI results to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, wmi

I searched since a while for an answer, but i didn't find any answer that match with my need.

My problem is the following:
I made some wmi request to retrieve some informations about remote computers. But i want some of these information to be displayed on a datagridview. I have no idea how to populate my datagridview promatically.

My request is pretty simple, and my results are displayed correctly to the console : It displyas installed software, with somme needed infos.

```
 public void getInstalledSoftwares(string hostname)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + hostname + "\\root\\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        foreach (ManagementObject product in searcher.Get())
        {

            Object Name = product["Name"].ToString();
            Object Version = product["Version"].ToString();
            /*
             * [...]
             **/ 

            // Populate the datagridview ?

            Console.WriteLine(Name + " --- " + Version);
        }

    }
```

The button that launch this request is localized in another class. So I tried things like this :

```
Form.mydgv.Rows.add(name);
```

It tells me that there is not any definition for rows. Then, i don't know if it is a good idea, but my Datagridview is "pre-made" with needed column, like this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_software"  Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Application" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Editeur" Width="Auto"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Installé le" Width="Auto"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Localisation" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Taille" Width="Auto"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Version" Width="Auto"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Uninstall" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Thank's a lot for your help.

Comment: save data from wmi in new object collection and bind this collection to dataGrid, also need to refresh grid columns scheme

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - 
__Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Thx. The name here is temporary, for my test purpose. I will rename it afterwards, following good practice. I haven't enough reputation to tag correcty, unfortunally.
Could you please show me an example, as i'm pretty new with datagridview, and its datasource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) and bind the DataGrid to the resulting collection:

```
var products = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product").ToList();

mydgc.ItemsSource = products;
```

Comment: It works fine ! thank's for that. But I have a subsidiary question. Why ORMi is so little known ?

Comment: @Neandril I wrote it a couple of months ago. And did not much publicity :D

Comment: oh ok :) It's a pretty nice tool. And good job for writing it :)